# store Postman tests without passwords

Tags: rest, authorization, netsuite, postman

I've been using Postman to test my NetSuite RESTlets for quite a while.  I'd like to be able store my tests on the net and share them with my collaborators, but I've not been able to figure out how to get it to ***not*** store passwords.

NetSuite uses a header like this:

```
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=123456,nlauth_email=user@domain.com,nlauth_signature=plainTextPassword,nlauth_role=321
```

I'd like a way to put a tag in place of "plainTextPassword" and have postman prompt for and temporarily store that password and send it with the requests, but not store it with the test collections and lose it when Postman exits.

Any ideas on how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

Postman allows you to define environments (profiles). Using an environment you can define a variable for your password, let say for example `NetSuite_Password`, and then replace your plain password at the headers by `{{NetSuite_Password}}`. When testing, Postman will replace the tag by the specific value depending on the active environment, but when exporting it will keep the tag.

[Setting up an environment with variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments)

[Using environments to switch contexts](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/test_multi_environments)

Answer (score 0):

`Netsuite` offers 2 ways of authentications:

1. `NLAuth` which is password based
2. `OAuth` which is token based

Use `OAuth` , the whole point of it is not to use password